# Force validation of ria entity in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, validation, ria

I have a situation in which I will load invalid data.  I'm using a DataForm to edit the data and I need to force a validation.  The user might not normally edit the fields which are invalid but before I save the entity back I would like to notify the user that they need to be edited.  But the validation does not seem to fire unless the property is actually changed.  Is there a way to force an entity to run all client side validation rules?

Shane Holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this exact problem. I ended up implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo on my viewmodel (actually in a base class), and validating the validation context like so...

```
// Clear any validation errors already registered
CurrentUser.ValidationErrors.Clear();

var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
ValidationContext vcontext = new ValidationContext(CurrentUser, null, null);

// Validate the User; the results are added to our list of validationResults
Validator.TryValidateObject(CurrentUser, vcontext, validationResults);

// Add the errors to the entities validation error list
foreach (var res in validationResults)
{
    CurrentUser.ValidationErrors.Add(res);
}
```

I can't remember off the top of my head, but if that doesn't trigger the ValidationStates on your view (i.e. a red border on the textbox), add the errors to the viewmodel's ValidationErrors collection (created in the implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo).

```
// Add the errors to the viewmodel's validation error list
foreach (var res in validationResults)
{
    CurrentUser.ValidationErrors.Add(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I undertood correctly what you want to achive...

If you add a custom validator on the server and just rename the class file as `whatever.shared.cs` that **shared** tells the compiler (?) to add that validator to run on the client...

Take a look at [this post](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/07/27/silverlight-and-wcf-ria-services-6-validation.aspx)

hope that helps...